# How do we add a tag or vote for a new tag

Tags: feature-request

I want to add the tag category theory or cateogorical quantum mechanics or something like categorical physics.  How can I ask to have this tag added?  There is a huge group at Oxford, there's Isham and Doering, and so many others.  We should add a tag so that we can just post to the general idea of using category theory in physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have [at least 300 reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags), you can just add the tag to any questions that should have it. There's an "edit tags" link that will appear (I think) if you hover your mouse just to the right of the existing tags, or you can just use the regular "edit" link if you have it.

Comment: NB: [Limit has changed from 300 to 1k](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5616/2451).